# Exchanging data with ES6 classes and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find a way to exchange data using JSON and ES6 classes.

Suppose that I have the following ES6 class definition:

```
export default class Point {
    constructor(data = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    get x() { return this._x; }
    set x(val) { this._x = val; }
    get y() { return this._y; }
    set y(val) { this._y = val; }
}
```

And the following object instance:

```
let jsonIn = JSON.parse("{"x": "34", "y": "28"}");
let myPoint = new Point(jsonIn);
```

Upon inspection, `myPoint` will correctly have two "internal" attributes named `_x` and `_y` set to 34 and 28, respectively. So object hydration from JSON to an ES6 class instance is possible.

However, if I now try to serialize this instance back to JSON:

```
let myJson = JSON.stringify(myPoint);
```

I get the following:

```
> "{"_x":"34","_y":"28"}"
```

Is it possible or legal to name the serialized JSON keys as the object's public property getter names instead? Something like this?

```
> "{"x": "34", "y": "28"}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ES6 Class to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33382939/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hasn't changed with ES2015. You still simply define a custom [**`toJSON`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) method:

```
toJSON() {
  return {x: this.x, y: this.y};
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I had no idea there was a hook into the serialization mechanism. That should be enough to solve my problem. Much appreciated! :D.