# JSON stringify ES6 class property with getter/setter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, stringify, es6-class

I have a JavaScript ES6 class that has a property set with `set` and accessed with `get` functions. It is also a constructor parameter so the class can be instantiated with said property.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(property) {
    this.property = property
  }

  set property(prop) {
  // Some validation etc.
  this._property = prop
  }

  get property() {
    return this._property
  }
}
```

I use `_property` to escape the JS gotcha of using get/set that results in an infinite loop if I set directly to `property`.

Now I need to stringify an instance of MyClass to send it with a HTTP request. The stringified JSON is an object like:

```
{
   //...
   _property:
}
```

I need the resulting JSON string to preserve `property` so the service I am sending it to can parse it correctly. I also need `property` to remain in the constructor because I need to construct instances of MyClass from JSON sent by the service (which is sending objects with `property` not `_property`).

How do I get around this? Should I just intercept the MyClass instance before sending it to the HTTP request and mutate `_property` to `property` using regex? This seems ugly, but I will be able to keep my current code.

Alternatively I can intercept the JSON being sent to the client from the service and instantiate MyClass with a totally different property name. However this means a different representation of the class either side of the service.

Comment: `MyClass.prototype.toJson` might help you

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar: `toJSON` - note the capitalisation

Comment: Related: [Convert ES6 Class with Symbols to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33382939/1048572)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [`toJSON` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) to customise the way your class serialises to JSON:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(property) {
    this.property = property
  }

  set property(prop) {
  // Some validation etc.
  this._property = prop
  }

  get property() {
    return this._property
  }

  toJSON() {
    return {
      property: this.property
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend calling the getter though, not `._property`

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of this!

Answer (score 25):

If you want to avoid calling toJson, there is another solution using enumerable and writable:

```
class MyClass {

  constructor(property) {

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        _property: {writable: true, enumerable: false},
        property: {
            get: function () { return this._property; },
            set: function (property) { this._property = property; },
            enumerable: true
        }
    });

    this.property = property;
  }

}
```

Comment: You don't call `toJSON`. It is automatically called by `JSON.stringify`. See [`JSON.stringify`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify) step 12, and [`SerializeJSONProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-serializejsonproperty) step 3.

Comment: That is a good point. Anyway, when you have more properties in your class toJSON method gets bigger and more complex. You need to update it everytime you add/remove a property. I still think it is better to avoid it.

Comment: FYI this also works with constructor function style "classes".

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by @Amadan you can write your own [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) method.

Further more, in order to avoid re-updating your method every time you add a property to your class you can use a more generic `toJSON` implementation.

```js
class MyClass {

  get prop1() {
    return 'hello';
  }
  
  get prop2() {
    return 'world';
  }

  toJSON() {

    // start with an empty object (see other alternatives below) 
    const jsonObj = {};

    // add all properties
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {      
      const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, key);
      const hasGetter = desc && typeof desc.get === 'function';
      if (hasGetter) {
        jsonObj[key] = desc.get();
      }
    }

    return jsonObj;
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
const json = JSON.stringify(instance);
console.log(json); // outputs: {"prop1":"hello","prop2":"world"}
```

If you want to emit all properties **and all fields** you can replace `const jsonObj = {};` with

```
const jsonObj = Object.assign({}, this);
```

Alternatively, if you want to emit all properties **and some specific fields** you can replace it with

```
const jsonObj = {
    myField: myOtherField
};
```

Comment: That seems to produce both `_property` and `property`

Comment: You are right. I wasn't paying enough attention to the details of the quedtion :(   Never the less it is easy to fix. Just omit the Object.assign call and replace it with an empty object. This way you get all the properties without the fields.

Comment: I've edited the answer to more accurately fit the required result (and other common use cases).

Comment: I had to make 2 changes to make this code work: replace `const key of Object.keys(proto)` (only returns enumerable properties) with `const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)` (returns all properties) and `jsonObj[key] = desc.get();` (returns "undefined" instead of the value of the property) with `jsonObj[key] = this[key];`

Comment: I am actually using it in TypeScript and it works either way but you're right and I've updated the answer to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, thanks! As for the second part, as you can see from the now runnable snippet, it seems to work.

Answer (score 13):

I made some adjustments to the script of Alon Bar. Below is a version of the script that works perfectly for me.

```
toJSON() {
        const jsonObj = Object.assign({}, this);
        const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
            const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, key);
            const hasGetter = desc && typeof desc.get === 'function';
            if (hasGetter) {
                jsonObj[key] = this[key];
            }
        }
        return jsonObj;
    }
```

Comment: This one works great and can easily be put into a base class. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Use *private fields* for internal use.

```
class PrivateClassFieldTest {
    #property;
    constructor(value) {
        this.property = value;
    }
    get property() {
        return this.#property;
    }
    set property(value) {
        this.#property = value;
    }
}
```

---

```js
class Test {
 constructor(value) {
  this.property = value;
 }
 get property() {
  return this._property;
 }
 set property(value) {
  this._property = value;
 }
}

class PublicClassFieldTest {
 _property;
 constructor(value) {
  this.property = value;
 }
 get property() {
  return this.property;
 }
 set property(value) {
  this._property = value;
 }
}

class PrivateClassFieldTest {
 #property;
 constructor(value) {
  this.property = value;
 }
 get property() {
  return this.#property;
 }
 set property(value) {
  this.#property = value;
 }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Test("test")));
console.log(JSON.stringify(new PublicClassFieldTest("test")));
console.log(JSON.stringify(new PrivateClassFieldTest("test")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer) to solve such problem: stringify an instance of JavaScript class, so that it can be sent with HTTP request:

```
// Client side
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
const serializedText = ESSerializer.serialize(anInstanceOfMyClass);
// Send HTTP request, with serializedText as data
```

On service side, use esserializer again to deserialize the data into a perfect copy of `anInstanceOfMyClass`, with all getter/setter fields (such as `property`) retained:

```
// Node.js service side
const deserializedObj = ESSerializer.deserialize(serializedText, [MyClass]);
// deserializedObj is a perfect copy of anInstanceOfMyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but I have no access to the class construction and I'm not able to add or override the ToJson method

here is the solution that helped me solve it

a simple class with getters and properties

```
class MyClass {
    jack = "yoo"
    get prop1() {
        return 'hello';
    }

    get prop2() {
        return 'world';
    }

}
```

a class with a child class and also child object with getters

```
class MyClassB {
    constructor() {
        this.otherClass = new MyClass()
    }
    joe = "yoo"
    otherObject = {
        youplaboum: "yoo",
        get propOtherObject() {
            return 'propOtherObjectValue';
        }
    }
    get prop1() {
        return 'helloClassB';
    }


    get prop2() {
        return 'worldClassB';
    }

}
```

here is the magic recursive function inspired by the ToJSON made by [@bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2546179/bits)

```
const objectWithGetters = function (instance) {
    const jsonObj = Object.assign({}, instance);
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(instance);
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
        const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, key);
        const hasGetter = desc && typeof desc.get === 'function';
        if (hasGetter) {
            jsonObj[key] = desc.get();
        }
    }
    for (let i in jsonObj) {
        let value = jsonObj[i];
        if (typeof value === "object" && value.constructor) {
            jsonObj[i] = objectWithGetters(value);
        }
    }
    return jsonObj;
}


const instance = new MyClassB();
const jsonObj = objectWithGetters(instance)
console.log(jsonObj)

let json = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
console.log(json)
```