# JSON Serialization of classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, es6-class

A simple and obvious issue I've just stumbled on is serializing to JSON using `JSON.stringify`.

If you're not aware already, it doesn't work, `JSON.stringify` won't use any of the getters:

```
class MyClass {
  get m() { return 1; }
}

JSON.stringify(new MyClass()); // writes empty object {}
```

Am I missing something regarding JSON serialization? I am already aware of implementing toJSON().

Classes still seem half baked after many years, I am starting to question why use them after all.

Comment: maybe this already answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294127/3125277

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33386327/1048572

Comment: Your `m`  property is neither enumerable nor an own property of the instance (it's inherited from the prototype). Both of which would be required to make it recognised by `JSON.stringify`. Use `constructor() { this.m = 1; }`  instead